# Find an enclosed formula for $a_n$ where $a_n$ is the $n$th term of the sequence $1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have reached that the formula should look something like this
$$a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^{f(n)}}{2}$$
where $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a function which outputs an even number if the $n$th term of the sequence is $1$ and an odd number if the $n$th term is $0$.

I tried manipulating the sequence a bit but haven't reached any conclusion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is one $1$ followed by one $0$ followed by two $1$s followed by two $0$s followed by three $1$s followed by three $0$s ... beginning with $a_0=1$, then it is [OEIS A118175](https://oeis.org/A118175) and can be written with ceiling and rounding functions $$a_n=1 - \lceil \sqrt{n+1} \,\rceil + [\sqrt{n+1}\,]$$

but there are other possibilities for what it is, including [$16$ listed at OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Yes, probably you could use an indicator or sign function combined with a trigonometric function

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like $n$ $1$'s followed by $n$ $0$'s, for $n = 1,2,3, \ldots$.
If the indexing starts from $0$, the $n$ $1$'s are in positions $n^2+n$ to $(n+1)^2-1$.  Thus $a_k$ is the indicator function of $\{k \in \mathbb N:k \ge \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor^2 + \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor\}$