# What is the closed form for the sequence $1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, pattern-recognition

I thought about $$\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}$$ but it didn't work !
Is there any closed form for it ?

Comment: You're not too far off. At least that's the first thing I would try. The next part is to exchange $k$ for some sequence that's even and odd at the right times. Just the natural numbers alternates between even and odd, so that's not what you want.

Comment: Well, if you want to use this $(-1)^{\text{something}}$-approach, then you probably want "something" to be
$$
\text{even},~
\text{odd},~
\text{odd},~
\text{even},~
\text{even},~
\text{odd},~
\text{odd},~
\text{odd},~\ldots
$$

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3886254/42969

Comment: $$\dfrac{1-(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{4k-1}\rfloor}}{2}$$ or $$\dfrac{1+(-1)^{\lceil\sqrt{4k}\rceil}}{2}.$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an enclosed formula for $a_n$ where $a_n$ is the $n$th term of the sequence $1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,\dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886254/find-an-enclosed-formula-for-a-n-where-a-n-is-the-nth-term-of-the-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence can be broken to chucks with even lengths, i.e.
$$
{
0<k\le2\implies f(k)=1-\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor
\\
2<k\le6\implies f(k)=1-\lfloor\frac{k}{5}\rfloor
\\
\vdots
\\
u(u+1)<k\le(u+1)(u+2)\implies f(k)=1-\lfloor\frac{k}{(u+1)^2+1}\rfloor
}
$$
From the other side ,
$$
{
u(u+1)<k\le(u+1)(u+2)
\\\iff u^2+u<k\le u^2+3u+2
\\\iff 4u^2+4u<4k\le 4u^2+12u+8
\\\iff 4u^2+4u+1<4k+1\le 4u^2+12u+9
\\\iff (2u+1)^2<4k+1\le (2u+3)^2
\\\iff 2u+1<\sqrt{4k+1}\le 2u+3
\\\iff 2u+2\le \sqrt{4k+1}< 2u+4
\\\iff u+1\le \sqrt{k+0.25}< u+2
\\\iff u+1=\lfloor \sqrt{k+0.25}\rfloor
\\\iff u=\lfloor \sqrt{k+0.25}\rfloor-1
}.
$$
Finally, the general term becomes

> $$f(k)=1-\left\lfloor\frac{k}{1+\left\lfloor\sqrt{k+0.25}\right\rfloor^2}\right\rfloor$$

It can also be expressed as
$$
f(k)=\frac{1+(-1)^{g(k)}}{2},
$$
where
$$
g(k)=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{1+\left\lfloor\sqrt{k+0.25}\right\rfloor^2}\right\rfloor
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. One is the sequence which is $1$ if $n$ product of odd number of primes and $0$ if $n$ is the product of even number of primes.
This sequence starting from $n\ge 5$ is given by
$$
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
$$
A second possibility is the common residue of $\binom{3n}{n}/(2n+1)$ modulo 2. A third one, the number of times the digit $2$ appears in the decimal expansion of $n^3$.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A118175), this formula works:
$$
\left \lfloor \sqrt{k+1} + \frac1{2} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \sqrt{k} \right \rfloor
$$